# Encoding in Pig

Tags: encoding, utf-8, apache-pig

Loading data that contains some particular characters (as for example, À, ° and others) using Pig Latin and storing data in a .txt file is possible to see that these symbols in a txt file are displayed as ï¿½ and ï characters. That happens because of UTF-8 substitution character.
I would like to ask if is possible to avoid it somehow, maybe with some pig commands, to have in the result (in txt file) for example À instead of ï¿½?

Comment: are you sure that the source is utf-8 encoded? If not, you would have to implement your own storage functions to support other encodings.

Answer (score 3):

In Pig we have built in dynamic invokers that that allow a Pig programmer to refer to Java functions without having to wrap them in custom Pig UDFs. So now u can load the data as UTF-8 encoded strings, then decode it, then perform all your operations on it and then store it back as UTF-8. I guess this should work for the first part:

```
    DEFINE UrlDecode InvokeForString('java.net.URLDecoder.decode', 'String String');
    encoded_strings = LOAD 'encoded_strings.txt' as (encoded:chararray);
    decoded_strings = FOREACH encoded_strings GENERATE UrlDecode(encoded, 'UTF-8');
```

The java code responsible for doing this is:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URLDecoder;

    import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
    import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

    public class UrlDecode extends EvalFunc<String> {

        @Override
        public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
            String encoded = (String) input.get(0);
            String encoding = (String) input.get(1);
            return URLDecoder.decode(encoded, encoding);
        }
    }
```

Now modify this code to return UTF-8 encoded strings from normal strings and store it to your text file. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct this is because of **Text** (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html) converts incoming data (Bytes) to UTF-8 automatically. To avoid this you should not work with Text.

That said you should use **bytearray** type instead of **chararray** (**bytearray** do not use Text and so no conversion is done). Since you don't specify any code, I'll provide an example for illustration:

1. this is what (likely) you did:

   ```
   converted_to_utf = LOAD 'strangeEncodingdata' using TextLoader AS (line:chararray);
   ```
2. this is what you wanted to do:

   ```
   no_conversion = LOAD 'strangeEncodingdata' using TextLoader AS (line:bytearray);
   ```