# PIG UDF (Python) Charset Encoding

Tags: python, hadoop, encoding, utf-8, apache-pig

i'm a beginner in writing Python and Pig UDF's and struggling with the charset conversion of an input file using PIG.

Browsed stackoverflow and the whole internet for days, tried a bunch of different things but I'm still helpless.

Hopefully someone can give me a gentle push into the right direction.

---

Environment: a real distributed Hadoop cluster (no local instance) / Cloudera configured with `utf-8` and `Apache Pig version 0.12.0`

My source file is encoded with `iso-8859-1` and the goal is to store it's content as `utf-8` (after or before several other operations within pig).

The input file looks like this (a couple of ASCII/iso-8859-1 characters for testing purpose - one char each line):

```html
ù
û
ü
ÿ
à
â
æ
ç
é
è
ê
ë
î
ô
```

This is my Pig-Script:

```html
RMF $output;

REGISTER 'charsetConversion.py' using org.apache.pig.scripting.jython.JythonScriptEngine AS pyudf;

data = LOAD '$input' USING PigStorage() AS (col1:chararray); --col1:bytearray

final = foreach data generate $0, pyudf.toUTF8(col1);

STORE final INTO '$output' USING PigStorage();
```

And my UDF (written in python):

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python
# charsetConversion.py

@outputSchema("word:chararray")
def toUTF8(s):
    return unicode(s, 'iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
```

After running/submitting the script I got following output:

```html
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
� ï¿½
```

In the second  column i would expect the same readable values as in the input file and not `ï¿½`.

What happens here?

Is my approach recommended at all?

What kind of other approaches does exist (without java [Stackoverflow: Encoding in Pig - Java solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979454/encoding-in-pig/24449254#24449254))?

Thanks a lot in advance and for any advises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was solving a similar problem.
Yes, the character encoding might be tricky in Java/Hadoop world :).

Actually, you were pretty close - the solution is:

```
data = LOAD '$input' USING PigStorage() AS (col1:bytearray);
```

The problem was that you specified col1 as a chararray. Chararray is "a array (string) in Unicode UTF-8 format". However, this is not true for your input data that are in *iso-8859-1*. The pig script interpreted your data as UTF-8 *instead* of *iso-8859-1*. You should specify **bytearray** instead. Bytearray do not interpret the data in any way - you have to do it (e.g. in your UDF function).

In the next, line we need to process each line:

```
parsed = foreach a generate flatten(my.testparser($0));
```

Then, within UDF function (my.testparser()) we will change *iso-8859-1* encoding into *utf-8*:

```
  ....
  val line:String = input.get(0).asInstanceOf[DataByteArray].get(), "windows-1250")
  ....
```

The code is in scala (I'm not a python guy - sorry), it takes input  *DataByteArray* (*bytearray* in PIG) and get array of *Scala.Bytes*. Those bytes are interpreted as windows-1250 then.

That said, your UDF should stay the same, but the input needs to be changed into to *bytearray* in Pig  and equivalent data type in your UDF

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Here's the UDF defined in Python that worked for me for those of you who aren't comfortable with Scala:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# charsetConversion.py
import struct

@outputSchema("word:chararray")
def toUTF8(s):
        line = ‘.’join([struct.pack(‘B’, x).decode(‘iso-8859-1’) for x in s])
        return line
```

Here are the PIG commands to register the UDF, load the data, apply the UDF to the data, and get a sample of that data to check if the decoding worked as expected.

```
REGISTER 'charsetConversion.py' USING org.apache.pig.scripting.jython.JythonScriptEngine AS pyudf;
data = LOAD '$input' USING TextLoader AS (col1: bytearray);
final = FOREACH data GENERATE $0,pyudf.toUTF8(col1);
final_lim = LIMIT final 10;
DUMP final_lim;
```

As [xhudik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1408096/xhudik) mentioned in his answer, the important part here is to define your field as a byte array.